# doctrine, query builder: group by with strict SQL mode

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I had this request:

```
$builder = $this->createQueryBuilder('ord')
->where('ord.customerId = :cId')
->andWhere('ord.orderId IN (:orderIds)')
->groupBy('ord.orderId');
```

It worked fine: all object 'ord', but only one when the same: `ord.orderId`.

Since we are in **strict SQL mode** I have to add 'ord' in the GROUP BY `(->groupBy('ord','ord.orderId'))`.

Now my group on `orderId` doesn't work: I have several 'ord' with the same `ord.orderId`. (I want only one of them).

`ANY_VALUE()` is not working with the query builder, how can I do it?

Comment: Why do you need to use group by? there is a high chance than you don't really need to use group by: Doctrine is object oriented and you could easily do `$customer->getOrders()`

Comment: Yes, that's what I did finally. I did a sort on my results to keep only one 'ord' for each 'orderId'. But i would have liked to do it directly on my request.

Comment: Yeah but you really have to stop thinking "sql" and think doctrine objects if you don't want to loose a lot of time on the queries ^^